# How can I increase a quantity by one and keep track of the item that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to create a counter that keeps track of every time a user clicks on size, so far my only keeps track of the first item that was clicked effectively but after another size is clicked, it keeps track of the previously clicked size.

How can I make a counter for each item that was clicked independently of the next size clicked?

> This is the link to my code sandbox, and the function is on the
>   "productPage": https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-roentgen-7mp0t

This is my state:

```
this.state = { sizeQuantity: 0,   chosenSize: [], afterState: '', newState: [], list: [] };
```

This is my function:

```
 updateArray = (products, product, delta) => {
    this.seenItems.push({
      ...product,
      newStock: product.stock,
      product: this.state.sizeQuantity,
      delta
    });

    const tester = [];
    const result = [];
    this.seenItems.forEach(function(el) {
      if (tester.indexOf(el._id) === -1) {
        tester.push(el._id);
        result.push({ ...el });
      }
    });

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      chosenSize: result.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        newStock: (item.stock += delta),
        product: (prevState.sizeQuantity += 1)
      }))
    }));
  };
```

The `item.stock` is also not decreasing by one on each click either.

Comment: I think you should start with rewrite the state to `useReducer`. It will be simpler when you will have granulated elements like actions to modify state.

Comment: Mmmh would you be able to give me a quick example of how to go about doing that?